# DBI: quote_identifier and columns

Tags: perl, dbi

In the [DBI/quote_identifier](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#quote_identifier) documentation there are two syntaxes:

```
$sql = $dbh->quote_identifier( $name );
$sql = $dbh->quote_identifier( $catalog, $schema, $table, \%attr );
```

And the examples are about table names.

Is there something to object if one uses `quote_identifier` like this to quote columns:

```
$sql = $dbh->quote_identifier( undef, $table, $column );
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @jordanm, I have some join statements where the column name alone doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is fine. `quote_identifier` cannot and does not try to distinguish between table names and column names, and every database that I know has the same syntax for them. The only problem comes when you want column names like `schema.table.column`, which you will have to construct yourself from multiple calls to `quote_identifier`.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special about that.
Just try it.
Here is an example:
https://metacpan.org/source/BEROV/DBIx-Simple-Class-0.991/lib/DBIx/Simple/Class.pm#L305